# How to set the column values of some rows the same as the some other ones in the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Table schema :

```
+----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name                 | varchar(10)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| slno                 | varchar(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| type                 | int(2)        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| details              | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

name, slno and type together form a key.

Sample data :

```
+---------+------+------+-------------------------------+
| name    | slno | type | details                       |
+---------+------+------+-------------------------------+
| name1   | 11   |    1 | {"data":["feats1","feats2"] } |
| name1   | 11   |    2 | {"data":["feats1","feats2"] } |
| name1   | 12   |    1 | {"data":["feats5","feats6"] } |
| name1   | 12   |    2 | {"data":["feats5","feats6"] } |
| name2   | 11   |    1 | {"data":["feats3","feats4"] } |
| name2   | 11   |    2 | {"data":["feats3","feats4"] } |
| name2   | 12   |    1 | {"data":["feats7","feats8"] } |
| name2   | 12   |    2 | {"data":["feats10"] }         |
+---------+------+------+-------------------------------+
```

So basically for every entry with name = 'name1', there's a similar entry with same slno but with name = 'name2'.
What I want to do is set details as the same for rows with same slno and type but different name, i.e, above sample data set should like below. **name2** rows' details should match **name1** rows' details if they have same slno and type.

```
+---------+------+------+-------------------------------+
| name    | slno | type | details                       |
+---------+------+------+-------------------------------+
| name1   | 11   |    1 | {"data":["feats1","feats2"] } |
| name1   | 11   |    2 | {"data":["feats1","feats2"] } |
| name1   | 12   |    1 | {"data":["feats5","feats6"] } |
| name1   | 12   |    2 | {"data":["feats5","feats6"] } |
| name2   | 11   |    1 | {"data":["feats1","feats2"] } |
| name2   | 11   |    2 | {"data":["feats1","feats2"] } |
| name2   | 12   |    1 | {"data":["feats5","feats6"] } |
| name2   | 12   |    2 | {"data":["feats5","feats6"] } |
+---------+------+------+-------------------------------+
```

I tried, but couldn't come up with a command to execute the above result. Can someone please help?

Comment: So slno and details should form a separate table?

Comment: No, I gave the sample data(2nd table) and how it should be transformed below it(last table)

Comment: How do you chose the reference value for a given `slno / type` couple? I mean, why do you pick `name1`'s value instead of `name2`'s one?

Comment: It's my requirement - assign name1's details to corresponding name2's details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the requirement is to give name2 details the values from name1 details, you can do that in MySQL with a `join` based update

```
update  yourTable as t1
join    yourTable as t2
on      t1.slno = t2.slno and
        t1.type = t2.type
set     t2.details = t1.details
where   t2.name = 'name2' and
        t1.name = 'name1'
```

You can achieve the same also moving the conditions I put in the `where` clause to the `join` conditions

```
update  yourTable as t1
join    yourTable as t2
on      t1.slno = t2.slno and
        t1.type = t2.type and
        t2.name = 'name2' and
        t1.name = 'name1'
set     t2.details = t1.details
```

You can see both queries in action **[here](http://rextester.com/QYWM85920)**